# How we call recursive function in node js

Tags: node.js

My code is below:

```
  module.exports = {
    cleanCode: function(){
      return 'clean code helper'
    },

    nestedChildren: function(arr, parentId) {
    var out = []
    for (var i in arr) {
      if (arr[i].parent_id == parentId) {
        var children = nestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)

        if (children.length) {
          arr[i].subCate = children
        }
        out.push(arr[i])
      }
    }
    return out
  }
}
```

Getting following error `{"message":"nestedChildren is not defined"}`

Comment: Move the function definition _outside_ the `module.exports` object?

Comment: How may i use after this ?

Comment: function nestedChildren(arr, parentId) {
    var out = []
    for (var i in arr) {
      if (arr[i].parent_id == parentId) {
        var children = nestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)

        if (children.length) {
          arr[i].subCate = children
        }
        out.push(arr[i])
      }
    }
    return out
  }   Also use this but getting same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) suggested, move the function outside of the `export`:

```js
let nestedChildren = function(arr, parentId) {
    var out = [];
    for (var i in arr) {
        if (arr[i].parent_id == parentId) {
            var children = nestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id);

            if (children.length) {
                arr[i].subCate = children;
            }
            out.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return out;
};

module.exports = {
    nestedChildren,
    cleanCode: function(){
        return 'clean code helper';
    }
};
```

Properties of an JavaScript Object cannot reference themselves or any other property of the same object. Thus, a recursive function within an object is not possible.

To work around this problem, you can move the function to the upper scope (outside of the object) where it's accessible from within the object.

So what I did was defining the function outside of the object as standalone function and then I referenced it in your `export`.

```js
module.exports = {
    nestedChildren,
    ...
};
```

is just a shorthand for

```js
module.exports = {
    nestedChildren: nestedChildren,
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you its working ,Please explain as well

Comment: @webdeveloper Hope it's clearer now. Let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: @webdeveloper No problem! Glad I could help :)